# How do I resolve this error for a react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: reactjs, input, react-bootstrap, typeahead, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have a child component called ProductCard that takes props from the parent called CreateNewSales. The onChange function takes two argument and is defined in the parent. If I call that function in the ProductCard, I keep getting this error for the typeahead though every other input except the quantity input seems to be working just fine. Here are the code:

This is the ProductCard:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { FormGroup, Label, Input, Col} from 'reactstrap';
import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {PlusSquare, MinusSquare} from 'react-feather'
const plusSquare = <PlusSquare/>
const minusSquare = <MinusSquare/>


const ProductCard = (props) => {

  console.log(props)

  const ProductOptions = [{id:1,name: "Clothes"}, {id:2,name:"Services"}, {id:3,name:"Shows"}, {id:4,name: "Peace"}] //dummy date  //res_data.payload.data.product

  // const [singleSelections, setSingleSelections] = useState([]);
  // from quantityIncrement.js
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

  const decrement = () => {
    if(count === 1){
      setCount(count)
    } else{
      setCount(count-1)
    }
  };

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count+1)
  };

  return(
    <Fragment>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>Product Name</Label>
        <Typeahead
          id="basic-typeahead"
          labelKey="name"
          onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e, props.index)}
          // onInputChange={props.setProductName}
          options={ProductOptions}
          name={ProductOptions}
          selected={props.value.productName}
          style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}}
          value={props.value.productName}
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <div className="form-row">
          <Col>
            <Label for="quantity">Quantity</Label>
            <div  style={{display: "flex"}}>
              <Input value={count} id="quantity" name="quantity" onChange={e=> setCount(e.target.value)} style={{backgroundColor: "#d5deee"}} />
              <div style={{display:"flex", marginTop:"5px"}}><span><i style={{ width: 15, fontSize: 10, padding: 11, color: '#848b97' }}  onClick={increment}>{plusSquare}</i></span><span><i style={{ width: 15, fontSize: 12, color: '#848b97' }} onClick={decrement}>{minusSquare}</i></span></div>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Label for="discount">Discount</Label>
            <Input type="text" id="discount" onChange = {(e) => props.handleChange(e, props.index)} value={props.value.discount} name="discount" style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}} />
          </Col>
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <div className="form-row">
          <Col>
            <Label for="price">Price</Label>
            <Input type="text" id="price" onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e, props.index)} value={props.value.price} name="price" style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}} />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Label for="amountPaid">Amount Paid</Label>
            <Input type="text" id="amountPaid" onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e, props.index)} value={props.value.amountPaid} name="amountPaid" style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}} />
          </Col>
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

ProductCard.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  // onClickQuantity: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}




export default ProductCard
```

This is the CreateNewSale:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import {Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Card, Col, Row, CardBody, Button, ButtonGroup, Table} from 'reactstrap';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify';
import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import { withRouter} from 'react-router';
// import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {validateCreateNewSaleForm, responseErrorParser} from "../../components/authentication/validator"

// productCard.js

import ProductCard from '../../components/sales/ProductCard'

import {Trash2} from 'react-feather'
const trash2 = <Trash2/>

const CreateNewSale = (props) => {

  const [, setIsCreatingNewSale]  = useState(false)
  // const [singleSelections, setSingleSelections] = useState([]);

  // from the productCard.js 

  const [newProductValues, setNewProductValues] = useState([{
    productName: [],
    discount: "",
    price: "",
    amountPaid: "",
    quantity: "1",
  }]);

  // const [newProductName, setNewProductName] = useState([{
  //   newProductNames: [],
  //   newCustomerName: []
  // }])

  // const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  //   setNewProductName({
  //     ...newProductName,
  //     [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  //   });
  // }

  const [customerName, setCustomerName] = useState([])
  const [date, setDate] = useState('')
  const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState('')
  const [vat, setVat] = useState('')
  // const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    console.log( event )
    const values = [...newProductValues];
    values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value
    console.log('=======================>', values)
    setNewProductValues(values);
    // setNewProductValues({
    //   ...newProductValues,
    //   [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    // });
  }

  const handleAddFields = (e) => {
    setNewProductValues([...newProductValues, {discount:"", price: "",
    amountPaid: "",
    quantity: "1",
    productName:[]
    }])
  }

  const handleRemoveFields = (index) => {
    const values  = [...newProductValues];
    values.splice(index, 1);
    setNewProductValues(values);
  }

  const customerOptions = [{id: 1, name: "Olalekan"}, {id: 2, name:"Michael"}, {id: 3,name:"Emeka"}, {id:4,name: "Glory"}] //dummy data  //res_data.payload.data.customer

  const fields = {
    customer_name: { default: '', message: 'Please enter an already created customer name' },
    product_name: { default: '', message: 'Please enter an already created customer name' },
    quantity: { default: '', message: 'Please select a quantity' },
    discount: { default: '', message: 'Please enter the discount given' },
    price: { default: '', message: 'Please select the price given' },
    amount_paid: { default: '', message: 'Please enter the amount paid by the customer' },
    date: { default: '', message: 'Please enter date' },
    due_date: { default: '', message: 'Please enter due date given' },
    vat: { default: '', message: 'Please enter the vat' },
  }

  const handleCreateNewSale = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setIsCreatingNewSale(true);
    const responsePayload = {
      customer_name: newProductValues.newCustomerName,  //customerName
      product_name: newProductValues.newproductNames,
      quantity: newProductValues.quantity,
      discount: newProductValues.discount,
      price: newProductValues.price,
      amount_paid: newProductValues.amountPaid,
      date: date,
      due_date: dueDate,
      vat: vat
    }
    const errors = validateCreateNewSaleForm(responsePayload, fields)
    if (errors.isErrors) {
      setIsCreatingNewSale(false)
      setTimeout(() => {
          errors.errors.forEach(e => toast.error(e.message))
      }, 400);
    } else {
      const response = await props.CreateNewSale(responsePayload)
      if (response.status) {
        const newSale = response.payload.data.id
        localStorage.setItem('__grm__act__biz__', newSale.toString())
        // props.history.push(`/business/${newSale}.toString/sales/invoice`, {previousLocation: props.location.pathname})
      } else {
        setIsCreatingNewSale(false)
        const payload = response.payload
        const errs = responseErrorParser(payload.data)
        setTimeout(() => {
            errs.forEach(e => toast.error(e.message))
        }, 400);
      }
    }
  }

  return(
    <Fragment>
      <div style={{display:"flex", fontFamily:"'Poppins', sans-serif"}}>
        <div className="col-lg-10"  style={{margin: "0 auto", maxWidth:"500px", width:"100%"}}>
          <Form>
            <Card>
              <CardBody>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label>Customer Name</Label>
                  <Typeahead
                    id="basic-typeahead"
                    labelKey="name"
                    onChange={setCustomerName}
                    options={customerOptions}
                    selected={customerName}
                    value={customerName}
                    name="customerName"
                    style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
            { newProductValues.map((newProductValue, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <Card >
                  <CardBody>
                    <Col style={{textAlign: "right"}}>
                      <i onClick={() => handleRemoveFields()} >{trash2}</i>
                    </Col>
                    <ProductCard index={index} handleChange={handleChange} value={newProductValue} />
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </div>  
            ))}
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <p onClick={() => handleAddFields()} style={{marginLeft:"20px"}}> <span style={{fontSize:"18px"}}>+</span> Add another product</p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <p onClick={() => handleAddFields()} style={{marginLeft:"20px"}}> <span style={{fontSize:"18px"}}>+</span> Add another product</p>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            <Card>
              <CardBody>
                <FormGroup>
                  <div className="form-row">
                    <Col>
                      <Label for="date">Date</Label>
                      <Input className="form-control digits" type="date" defaultValue="2018-01-01" value={date} onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)} id="date" name="date" style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <Label for="dueDate">Due Date</Label>
                      <Input className="form-control digits" type="date" defaultValue="2018-01-01" value={dueDate} onChange={e => setDueDate(e.target.value)} id="dueDate" name="dueDate" style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}} />
                    </Col>
                  </div>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <div className="form-row">
                    <Col>
                      <Label for="vat">VAT %</Label>
                      <Input type="text" id="vat" value={vat} onChange={e => setVat(e.target.value)} style={{backgroundColor:"#d5deee"}} />
                    </Col>
                  </div>
                </FormGroup>
                <div style={{margin:"0 auto", textAlign:"center"}}>
                  <p style={{fontSize:"12px"}}>Only click cleared if this sales have been paid in full</p>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <ButtonGroup>
                        <Button outline color="primary" type="button">Cleared</Button>
                        <Button outline color="primary" type="button">Not Cleared</Button>
                      </ButtonGroup>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </div>
                <Row className="m-t-50">
                  <Col lg={`6`}>
                    <Button outline color="primary" size="lg" style={{maxWidth:"200px", width:"100%"}}>SAVE</Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col lg={`6`}>
                    <Button color="primary" size="lg" onClick={e => handleCreateNewSale(e)} style={{maxWidth:"200px", width:"100%"}}>CREATE</Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-2" style={{backgroundColor:"#eaf6fd", position:"fixed", right:0, height:"100%",}}>
          <Card className="m-t-50">
            <CardBody>
              <div>You have added <span>0</span> products</div>              
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
          <div className="table-responsive">
            <Table borderless>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td className="bd-t-none">Sub Total</td>
                  <td>000 000 000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>
                  <td className="bd-t-none">Total</td>
                  <td>000 000 000</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </Table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  requestingCreateNewSale: state.isRequestingCreateNewSale,
});

const actions = {
  CreateNewSale: CreateNewSale
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(withRouter(CreateNewSale))
```

And this is the error I keep getting everytime I want to change the value for the productName typeahead:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
handleChange
src/pages/sales/CreateNewSales.js:54
  51 | const handleChange = (event, index) => {
  52 |   console.log( event )
  53 |   const values = [...newProductValues];
> 54 |   values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value
     | ^  55 |   console.log('=======================>', values)
  56 |   setNewProductValues(values);
  57 |   // setNewProductValues({
View compiled
onChange
src/components/sales/ProductCard.jsx:40
  37 | <Typeahead
  38 |   id="basic-typeahead"
  39 |   labelKey="name"
> 40 |   onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e, props.index)}
     | ^  41 |   // onInputChange={props.setProductName}
  42 |   options={ProductOptions}
  43 |   name={ProductOptions}
```

Comment: on line 52 of CreateNewSale you have a log of the event. how does it look like?

Comment: It's not logging out anything

Comment: does it not log out anything because of the build error? 
in that case what i meant is: 
if you removed the line 54 (the one that causes the error) and then would run the application until you hit that console log on line 52, then it should show you your event object

Comment: This is the log I see:

{index: 0, value: {…}, handleChange: ƒ}
handleChange: (event, index) => {…}
index: 0
value: {productName: "", discount: "", price: "", amountPaid: "", quantity: "1"}
__proto__: Object

Comment: when you hover over `event` in line 51. what type does it have?

Comment: (parameter) event: any

Comment: The typeahead change handler doesn't pass an event as the param; it passes an array of selections.